# numpy: multiply arrays rowwise

Tags: python, numpy

I have those arrays:

```
a = np.array([
     [1,2],
     [3,4],
     [5,6],
     [7,8]])

b = np.array([1,2,3,4])
```

and I want them to multiply like so:

```
[[1*1, 2*1],
[3*2, 4*2],
[5*3, 6*3],
[7*4, 8*4]]
```

... basically `out[i] = a[i] * b[i]`, where `a[i].shape` is `(2,)` and `b[i]` then is a scalar.

What's the trick? `np.multiply` seems not to work:

```
>>> np.multiply(a, b)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,2) (4)
```

Comment: The answer below uses a feature called `broadcasting`. You can read about it [here](http://scipy-lectures.github.io/intro/numpy/numpy.html#broadcasting), [here](http://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/advanced_numpy/#broadcasting) and [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html). It's also more standard to use the operator `*` rather than `multiply`

Comment: @YXD. You're right, although there are 2 things at play here - first reshape, then broadcast together. Nevertheless, I would rather insert a link to this question in the documentation, than the other way round - the theory behind broadcasting sounds very complicated, and seeing a simple example like this one, or e.g. a multiplication table on 2 `arange`s (outer product) gives a good concrete example.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

add an axis to b:

```
>>> np.multiply(a, b[:, np.newaxis])
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 6,  8],
       [15, 18],
       [28, 32]])
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I think I should spend some time figuring out what's the think with "axis" ...

Comment: `a * b[:, np.newaxis]` does not work for sparse matrices though. Using `multiply` works.

Answer (score 21):

For those who don't want to use `np.newaxis` or `reshape`, this is as simple as:

```
a * b[:, None]
```

This is because `np.newaxis` is actually an alias for `None`.

Read more [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis).

Answer (score 12):

```
>>> a * b.reshape(-1, 1)
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 6,  8],
       [15, 18],
       [28, 32]])
```

Comment: So what? Answering on SX not only helps authors but also the people who will reach this page in the future when they've encountered the same problem.

Answer (score 7):

What's missing here is the `einsum` ([doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html)) variant:

```py
np.einsum("ij,i->ij", a, b)
```

This gives you full control over the indices and `a` and `b` are passed blank.

Comment: As np.einsum was already available when the question was asked, I think this should be the accepted answer. The answer above uses additional memory I guess?

Answer (score -1):

It looks nice, but quite naive, I think,  because if you change the dimensions of a or b, the solution

```
np.mulitply(a, b[:, None])
```

doesn't work anymore.

I've always had the same doubt about multiplying arrays of arbitrary size row rise, or even, more generally, n-th dimension wise.

I used to do something like

```
 z = np.array([np.multiply(a, b) for a, b in zip(x,y)])
```

and that works for x or y that have dimension 1 or 2.

Does it exist with a method with "axis" argument like in other numpy methods? Such like

```
 z = np.mulitply(x, y, axis=0)
```