# numba: multiply arrays rowwise

Tags: python, arrays, numba

I have numpy arrays shapes (2,5) and (2,) and I want to multiply them rowvise

```
a = np.array([[3,5,6,9,10],[4,7,8,11,12]])
b = np.array([-1,2])
```

From [numpy: multiply arrays rowwise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22934219/11199684) I know this works with numpy:

```
a * b[:,None]
```

which gives correct output

```
array([[ -3,  -5,  -6,  -9, -10],
       [  8,  14,  16,  22,  24]])
```

But with numba it does not work any more, I get a bunch of error messages beyond me.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

@njit()
def fct(a,b):
    c = a * b[:,None]
    return c

a = np.array([[3,5,6,9,10],[4,7,8,11,12]])
b = np.array([-1,2])
A = fct(a, b)
print(A)
```

I put this code in a file named numba_questionA.py. Running it gives error messages:

```
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
No implementation of function Function(<built-in function getitem>) found for signature:
 
 >>> getitem(array(int32, 1d, C), Tuple(slice<a:b>, none))
 
There are 22 candidate implementations:
  - Of which 20 did not match due to:
  Overload of function 'getitem': File: <numerous>: Line N/A.
    With argument(s): '(array(int32, 1d, C), Tuple(slice<a:b>, none))':
   No match.
  - Of which 2 did not match due to:
  Overload in function 'GetItemBuffer.generic': File: numba\core\typing\arraydecl.py: Line 162.
    With argument(s): '(array(int32, 1d, C), Tuple(slice<a:b>, none))':
   Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
     TypeError: unsupported array index type none in Tuple(slice<a:b>, none)
  raised from numba_questionA.py

During: typing of intrinsic-call at numba_questionA.py
During: typing of static-get-item at numba_questionA.py

File "numba_questionA.py", line 6:
def fct(a,b):
    c = a * b[:,None]
    ^
```

Comment: Just write out the loops.  It isn't beneficial to use vectorized commands in Numba. You can also use parallelization, but this is only beneficial for larger arrays.

Comment: @max9111 I thought the efficiency of Numba is based on vectorization? I'm a novice on this but would like to understand more.

Comment: Every "vectorized" command except calls to other libraries (np,.dot,...) has to be rewritten to loops internally. The loop order is important for performance (first to last dimension, in C-ordered arrays). You can easily try this using the accepted answer. Two simple nested loops will be faster.

Comment: Nested loops in plain Python are extremely slow. Numpy helps by providing vectorized operations (compiled code written in C or Fortran) where you avoid explicit loops. Numba, in turn, produces compiled code where nested loops can be fast (following @max9111's advice). Numba also re-implements many Numpy vectorized operations, so their speed may be marginally better than original Numpy. Finally, Numba provides easy parallelization that may make a difference when dealing with large data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numba says it can't use None as an array index, so you can replace

```
b[:, None]
```

by

```
b.reshape(-1, 1)
```

However, Numba won't likely be faster than Numpy for an expression like `a * b[:,None]`.

But, if your arrays are *really* large, you can take advantage of Numba's parallelization:

```
@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def fct(a, b):
    c = np.empty_like(a)
    for i in nb.prange(a.shape[1]):
        c[:, i] = a[:, i] * b
    return c
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `guvectorize` is also a nice way to semi-automatically broadcast your data. A benefit is that you can compile for different targets (`cpu`, `parallel` or `cuda`).

For small arrays like your example, parallelization would probably only introduce overhead.

```
@nb.guvectorize(["void(int32[:], int32[:], int32[:])"], 
             "(n), ()->(n)", nopython=True, target="cpu")
def fct(a, b, out):
    out[:] = a * b

A = fct(a, b)
```

Recent Numba versions can also infer the datatypes automatically, if you're willing to provide the output array as well, and only compile for the `cpu` target, so:

```
@nb.guvectorize("(n),()->(n)", nopython=True, target="cpu")
def fct(a, b, out):
    out[:] = a * b

A = np.empty_like(a)
fct(a, b, A)
```